# Why can ListView rows get very very high randomly?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a `ListView` in the first row of a `Grid`. There is some data which fills each row by double clicking on items in the `GridControl` below. So the main idea of it is to click on a `GridControl` item so it may be seen in the `ListView` too.

The problem is very strange: the first item is always being added and looks normally in the `ListView`, but then the next items can get very large, in random order.

I haven't found any `ListView.Rows` property or similar. So I cannot explicitly set it how I want.

There is a Grid, in which ListView is keeping:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="200" x:Name="xSelectedRow"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="4"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

There is ListView with some columns:

```
<ListView x:Name="xListSelected" BorderBrush="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItemsSource}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSelectedItem}">

    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 2 4 2" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction
                Command="{Binding RemoveSelectedItemCommand}"  
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=SelectedItem}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <ListView.View>                        
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=xProjectViewId}">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Id}"
                                       FontSize="14"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=xName}" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}"
                                       FontSize="14"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView.Columns>                            
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Here is a link to an image: https://imgbbb.com/image/jkdJp

There is example in the image, where the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd rows are looking normally, but the fourth is very large. And it seems not always be like this: the next two rows can be normal, but then the next three are large again.

Have you ever seen such problem?

Comment: Your xaml looks messy, especially binding of the ListView. Is there any need for those names for your elements? Can you set CanContentScroll="False"?

Comment: @XAMIMAX, where shall I set it? And what will it give?

Comment: You would use databinding, i.e. amend the collection of the ListView and let the ListView handle newly added item. How do you add item to the list view?

Comment: I can't get to your image (security restrictions). What happens when you remove TextWrapping="Wrap"  from both the textblocks in the gridview?

Comment: @Andy, removing TextWrapping solves this, thank you, but know some strings are too long , so there is not enough space in column to display it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question about why some rows are higher is:

You set the textblocks to wrap and the strings in  them then make those controls grow.

It's not random.

Decide which you prefer.

The current increased height of some rows.

Truncating the strings by setting maxheight.

Lowering the size of (presumably) the Name variable so they can only enter so much.

Some mix.

Re-arranging your UI in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the grid you are talking about is written here:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200" x:Name="xSelectedRow"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="4"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Your height definitions for each row is inconsistent.

- A specific number will give it the specific height, but some parameters might change and scale this. So this would explain why your first row remains correct.
- A star (*) will tell the code to make the row proportional to the grid
- "Auto" make the row to adapt to the size of the content. Wraping and padding can make this give unexpected results.

I suggest to try to either give all of the rows a large enough specific height (200) or setting all of them to Star (*)

Comment: no the grid, you are talking about is container for ListView